# Need some sed magic: Moving marked lines to the beginning of a file

Tags: text-processing, sed, sort

I find myself in dire need of some `sed` magic (I *really* need to sit myself down and learn this).  I have a file with lots of lines.  After reviewing it, I've marked some lines by adding a star (*) to the beginning of the line.

What I would like to do with some `sed`trickery (if possible), is to move all the marked-lines to the beginning (or the end – I'm not picky) of the file, so they form a single block. The other lines (unmarked) should be left undisturbed.

How can I do something like this with `sed`?  I know `sed` has some buffers for moving text...

Answer (score 12):

is sed essential?  if you don't mind two passes through the source file, this is easily done with grep.

e.g.

```
grep '^\*' input > outputfile
grep -v '^\*' input >> outputfile
```

Comment: i think `grep '^*'` is proper syntax.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on the size of the file you can do:

```
sed '/^*/!H;//p;$!d;g;s/\n//'
```

That stacks in `H`old space lines which do not match `/^*/`. Those that do match are `p`rinted as they occur in input. Then all lines which are `!`not the `$`last are `d`eleted from output. On the last line we `g`et hold space by overwriting pattern space, then the first `\n`ewline character is `s/\n//`ubstituted away because the first `H`eld line will result in one extra every time.

That requires a big buffer though as it has store all of those lines in `H`old space. This, on the other hand...

```
sed '/^*/p;$!d;g;r file' <file    |
sed -e '1,/^$/{/./p;d' -e '};/^*/d'
```

...does not have that requirement.

The first `sed` `p`rints only `/^*/` matching lines until the `$`last line, at which time it prints a blank line then `r`eads out the entire input file all over again.

The second `sed` works first on a line range from the first line through the first blank line `p`rinting all lines which match at least a single character then `d`eleting the lot. After it encounters the first blank line, it then `d`eletes all lines which match `/^*/`.

Comment: The one-line `sed` solution creates an extra empty line if the input *only* consists of matched lines. Add a `;/^$/d` at the end of the command to fix this

Answer (score 6):

You don't need `sed` to do this, you can use some basic greps to pull the star (*) lines to the top. Say for example you had this file:

```
$ cat sample.txt 
1
2
3
4
* 5
* 6
* 7
8
9
10
```

Now to `grep` the sample.txt file putting the star (*) lines first:

```
$ cat <(grep '*' sample.txt) <(grep -v '*' sample.txt)
* 5
* 6
* 7
1
2
3
4
8
9
10
```

The above will run 2 greps, the 1st pulls all the lines with stars out, while the 2nd pulls all the non-starred lines. The output from these 2 commands is redirected as input to the `cat` command using the `<()` notation.

#### Alternative method

If you don't want to use cat + the 2 subshells you can do as was suggested by @terdon:

```
$ grep '*' sample.txt; grep -v '*' sample.txt
```

This will pull out all the lines from `sample.txt` that include a star (*) followed by all the lines that don't.

#### References

- [grep man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

Comment: OP probably didn't want their file sorted...

Comment: @sendmoreinfo - thanks didn't see that bit in the question, will adjust.

Comment: Why do you use `cat` and subshells? `grep '*' sample.txt;grep -v '*' sample.txt` will do exactly the same thing. Am I missing something?

Comment: @terdon - No reason just felt like doing it that way.

Comment: Ah, OK, I though it was some kind of arcane trickery I was not aware of :),

Comment: @terdon - I wrote it at 2AM this morning and just felt like doing it a little differently.

Comment: You don't have to use `cat`. This works as well: `tac <(grep '*' sample.txt) <(grep -v '*' sample.txt) > >(tac)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution using `ed` (and expanding a bit on the `vi` solution posted by Kaz, which underneath uses `ex` - a beefed up `ed`).
Replace `w` with `,p\n` to print the output instead of writing to file.

Move the matching lines to the end of the file:

```
ed -s file <<< $'g/^\*/m$\nwq\n'
```

The `g`lobal subcommand marks every line that matches the pattern. *Then, for each marked line, it sets the current line to the marked line and runs the subcommand*: `m`ove after the line at address `$` (after the last line); then `w`rite to file and `q`uit the editor.

Move the matching lines to the beginning of the file (or rather move the non matching lines to the end of the file - but it's the end result that matters - keep the line order):

```
ed -s file <<< $'v/^\*/m$\nwq\n'
```

The in`v`erse global subcommand marks every line that does NOT match the pattern. *Then, for each marked line, it sets the current line to the marked line and runs the subcommand*: `m`ove after the line at address `$` (after the last line); then `w`rite to file and `q`uit the editor.

The reason I use inverse match to achieve the desired result instead of `g/^\*/m0` (move all matching lines to the beginning) suggested by Kaz, is that (as he pointed out)  when you move the matching lines to the beginning they will end up in reverse order.
This - as I emphasized above - is because `g` and `v`, *for each marked line, set the current line to the marked line and run the specified subcommand(s)*. The first line marked as matching is moved after the line addressed by the parameter after `m`: `0` in this case - so it becomes the first line. Then the second matching line is moved to the same address so it becomes the first line and the line that was moved before it becomes the second line... and so on... until the last matching line is moved to the specified address.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind the empty line between the two blocks:

```
sed -n -e '/^* /{H;$!d}' -e '/^* /!p' -e '${g;p}'
```

or the other way round

```
sed -n -e '/^* /{p;$!d}' -e '/^* /!H' -e '${g;p}' file
```

Comment: To avoid the empty line between the two blocks you can do:
`sed -n -e '/^* /{p;$!d}' -e '/^* /!H' -e '${g;s/^\n//;p}' file`

Answer (score 1):

Since you added the `*` characters manually, you can just continue working interactively. In `vi`, you can do this:

```
:g/pattern/m<address>
```

to move all lines which match a pattern to the given address. If address is given as 0, it will move the lines before the first line of the file. So:

```
:g/^\*/m0
```

Note, however, that the marked lines appear in reversed order! I've done this kind of thing many times in the past. To keep the lines in order, what I do is move them after the last line instead of before the firstline, by using the address '$' instead of '0':

```
:g/^\*/m$
```

If I then want them at the front, then that's an easy manual move. For instance, using Vim's visual selection.

Next time, by the way, choose a marker which isn't a regex operator requiring escaping, though in this case Vim happens to accept `:g/^*/`. :)

It's possible to move the lines to the end, and delete the marking character in one step. This works in Vim; only problem is, I can't quite hunt down the piece of documentation which says that it's supposed to:

```
:g/^*/s/^.//|m$
```

Answer (score 0):

Here one way with `awk`:

```
awk '!/^\*/{a[++i]=$0;next}1 END{while(x<length(a))print a[++x]}' file
```

Comment: One minor glitch: `gawk` 4.1.0 I use requires semicolon between `1` and `END`. Does that code work for you as is, or the missing semicolon is just a copy-paste issue?

Comment: @manatwork Worked fine with the `awk` (bsd version) on my mac. But you are right, I tried with `gawk v4.1.0` and it didn't work.